# ¿Como alinear horizontalmente elementos dentro de un Media Object en Boostrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo uso del Media Object de Boostrap 4 para un modulo de comentarios , he añadido un botón en él pero no se como puedo alinearlo horizontalmente de forma que se quede  pegado al margen derecho.

El resultado deseado es el boton en esa posicion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.single-comment{
                border: 1px solid lightgray;
                padding: 15px;
                border-radius: 5px
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="media mb-4 single-comment"><img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Padre1</h5>
    <p>padre1</p>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm align-self-end mt-4">Responder</button>
   
   <div class="media mt-4"><img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Hijo</h5>
        <p>hijo</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno una de las forma de realizar eso es haciendo que el comentario "hijo" tome todo el ancho del card con `col-md-12` , y después hacer flotar el botón hacia la derecha con `float-right` el resultado sería el siguiente

```css
.single-comment {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="media mb-4 single-comment">
  <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Padre1</h5>
    <p>padre1</p>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right mt-4">
      Responder
    </button>

    <div class="media mt-4 col-md-12">
      <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Hijo</h5>
        <p>hijo</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva.Saludos!.

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 4** utiliza **.float-right** diferencia de **.pull-right** de **Bootstrap 3**.

Ejemplo:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary float-right">Responder</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero no me sirve .float-right , si bien es cierto que se queda al margen derecho el botón se queda a la altura del comentario hijo , y no del comentario padre. La dificultad es que el objeto Media es un flexbox y no consigo alinear los elementos dentro de el.

Comment: Ya veo, puedes compartir una imagen del resultado deseado.

Comment: He editado la pregunta y añadido una imagen con el resultado desseado

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mariscal/10ogrLa8/